# How do you extend a trait like itertools does with collect_vec()?

Tags: generics, rust, iterator, traits, scoping

I would like to create a method similar to the `collect_vec()` function in `itertools`.

Creating a small example by copying the `itertools` code:

```
pub trait MyItertools: Iterator {
    fn collect_vec(self) -> Vec<Self::Item>
        where Self: Sized
    {
        self.collect()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = (0..5).collect_vec();
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

I rather naively expect that the compiler will use my `collect_vec` as
`MyItertools` is in scope.

There must be some other magic that `itertools` is doing to get this to compile.

We get the error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `collect_vec` found for struct `std::ops::Range<{integer}>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:14:20
   |
14 |     let v = (0..5).collect_vec();
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `std::ops::Range<{integer}>`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `MyItertools` defines an item `collect_vec`, perhaps you need to implement it
  --> src/main.rs:5:1
   |
5  | pub trait MyItertools: Iterator {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Which is misleading as we have indeed implemented `collect_vec` in `MyItertools`.

One possible solution is to `impl MyItertools` for all flavours of
`Iterator`, but there does not seem to be a way to do this for all `Iterator` implementing traits and types.

Comment: No it's not, as you haven't actually implemented the `MyItertools` trait for `std::ops::Range` (which is what `(0..5)` is). You've declared the trait, but you haven't actually implemented it for any type (at least in your MCVE). To implement the trait on `SomeType`, you will have to add a `impl MyItertools for SomeType` block (and make sure that `SomeType` implements `Iterator` as well).

Comment: Thanks, EvilTalk. As I suggest in my edit, that would be possible to do for all the types I use, but Itertools does not seem to do this, hence the magic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The missing magic piece of the puzzle is a generic blanket implementation that implements the `MyItertools` trait for all types which implement the `Iterator` trait. Updated fixed example:

```rust
pub trait MyItertools: Iterator {
    fn collect_vec(self) -> Vec<Self::Item>
        where Self: Sized
    {
        self.collect()
    }
}

impl<T> MyItertools for T where T: Iterator {}

fn main() {
    let v = (0..5).collect_vec();
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7cd5cb21457c55f6b0468ca658ffae63)

Comment: Aha! Excellent answer, @pretzelhammer.